# Viewport Meta Tag not work with Google Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

I am currently working on my portfolio website with React. I am making the project responsive, so I added the following meta tag to my index.html file within the head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

The responsive design works on my phone and in Google Chrome dev tools under responsive; however when the page is in desktop view the responsive design does not work. I am working with Google Chrome Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit). I am attempting to integrate a react-strap menu tab when the device is a max-width of 800px. Again the react-strap menu is visible on my phone.

[navbar component including npm package react-responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm8zV.png)

[responsive CSS styling with media queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwtt8.png)

[Nav bar working with responsive dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIbvd.png)

[Nav bar not working in normal google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAowt.png)

Comment: add you meta tag on post.

Comment: Could you mention the chrome version which you are working on?

Comment: @DularaMalindu Currently working with Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)